# What does mysql_esp mean?

Tags: php, mysql

I encountered a code with following syntax , please help me understand it :

```
$reference_name = mysql_esp($_POST['reference_name']);
$passkey        = mysql_esp($_POST['passkey']);
$share          = mysql_esp($_POST['share']);
$user_type      = mysql_esp($_POST['user_type']);
```

Comment: Try [php.net](http://uk1.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=mysql_esp&scope=quickref), it says *mysql_esp doesn't exist. Closest matches:*

Comment: it's a custom function.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I agree, it seems like a custom wrapper for [mysql_real_escape_string](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php)

Comment: so tell us, where DID you get that piece of code anyway? there's no way for us to know, unless we spend more time than is needed to Google this.

Comment: Do a search across your code and look for `mysql_esp` as a function name

Comment: Firstly, mysql_* is deprecated, so you should refrain from using that. Secondly, there is no such term, function or code that I could find that matches or even relates to 'mysql_esp'.... either its custom or simply doesn't exist!

Answer (score 2):

What you have, seems to be a custom function. Nowhere in the docs can this be found (unless it's a very old deprecated function, which I doubt).

By the look of the name and how it is used, it seems you have a custom extension for [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php). Try to delve into the code and find where it is declared. A good IDE and understanding of how it works most likely will help you find this (I use F12 in VS2015 with PHP tools).

If you find the function, you can always post it on here and the community can help you find the answer to what it is/does